# Sequence of a number

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $a_n$ is such that $a_n = 2a_{n-1}+1$.  If $a_6= 191$ and $a_5 =95$, what is the value of $a_2$?

Answer (score 3):

Solve the recurrence for $a_{n-1}$ in terms of $a_n$, and work backwards: calculate $a_4$ from the known value of $a_5$, then use that to calculate $a_3$, and finally use that to calculate $a_2$. You can check your formula for $a_{n-1}$ in terms of $a_n$ by verifying that if you substitute $191$ for $a_6$, it really does give you $95$ for $a_5$.